# text in plot from column, first argument of a ";" divided string

Tags: r

one quick question

picture  a data frame like

```
data=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(4,5,6), Genes=c("AHS;AKS;AHS","AHS;IO","HU"))
```

so i want to plot x and y

```
plot(x,y)
```

and do the label for the dots like this

```
text(data$x+0.2,data$y+0.2,labels=data$Genes)
```

BUT i dont want to use all arguments from the genes column ONLY the first one (e.g. before the ";")
Can u please help me with that?
This is only an example, i have already read my data in with `read.delim`, so i cannot do a specific "read in" with string separation.

Comment: you can use regular expressions to do this.  `gsub('^([A-Z]+);.*$', '\\1', data$Genes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you can use `gsub` to do this:

```
gsub('^([A-Z]+);.*$', '\\1', data$Genes)
```

You could also use `strsplit`:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(data$Genes, ';'), '[', 1))
```

But that's yucky...

Its also probably worth mentioning the `stringr` package which collects a lot of these string munging functions in to a single place with predictable syntax and names.

Comment: @hendrik Glad to hear it.  If my response has answered your question, please click the check mark next to it so others can see that it has been resolved.